# Excel hangs when printing the first time from ASP.NET webservice

Tags: web-services, excel, printing, asmx, com-interop

We are using Excel to convert SpreatSheetML to XLS in an ASP.NET webservice. Moreover, if the user checks the right checkboxes, we spawn a thread that uses Excel to print the spreadsheet.

Recently, we have deployed the app in a new environment, and then we started having problems: the first time someone tries to print, Excel seems to hang on the server - i.e. the call to the `PrintOut` method on the workbook never returns.

But if we log in to the server as the application pool identity and open Excel, send something to the printer, and close it again, printing will work from then on!

I suspect that Excel is showing an `invisible dialog` - the symptoms are the same as we had earlier, a time when Excel seemed to stall on a "cannot use object linking and embedding"-dialog that appeared when Excel opened.

I know that using server-side Office automation is bad, but this is a legacy app that is very hard to change, so please don't just advise me to re-design our solution.

Has anyone had any experiences with this kind of behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, noone seems to have had this problem.

The really weird thing is that my night jobs (ordinary .NET .exe) are perfectly capable of printing - it's only my web services that have this problem.

So I solved the problem by doing what I should have done long ago: I made a simple Windows service with [Topshelf](http://code.google.com/p/topshelf/), that responds to some MSMQ messages and does the printing, and then my web services can order print-outs via a message queue.

Much nicer in every way!

Answer (score 1):

I've had no end of problems (poor performance, hanging processes, crashing processes etc) using Microsoft Excel, Word and PowerPoint through interop in a web service to print Office documents to PDF format. I too have faced problems that I suspect are because of invisible dialog boxes (maybe a file is corrupt, read-only recommended has been set, file is password protected, or whatever).

I know there are tools available that don't use Office, but they are very expensive. My solution was to switch to automating OpenOffice. OpenOffice seems to be much more stable, and I've left hanging processes and the like behind.

So, while I suppose I am saying "don't automate Microsoft Office", I'm not suggesting that you abandon automation altogether; just that I've had *much* more success automating OpenOffice than Microsoft Office.

Comment: It's possible that OpenOffice was designed to be automated in a server environment. It's _certain_ that Microsoft Office was not.

Answer (score 0):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can read xls or xlsx workbooks and can print to the default printer without displaying any dialog boxes (see the WorkbookView.Print() method).

You can download an evaluation [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Answer (score -2):

Like many people, I *have* seen this sort of behavior. It is caused by using the Office APIs in a server, especially a multithreaded ASP.NET application.

However, you've said you don't want to know about not shooting yourself in the foot, so there's little more to say. You seem to be trapped by the consequences of earlier foolishness.

---

OK, stop me if you've heard *this* one:

A man asks a question on StackOverflow. He says, "SO, bad stuff happens when I automate an Office application from inside a service". So, John Saunders says, "So, don't automate the Office application from inside a service. Automate it from inside a desktop application, as Microsoft intended to be done."

When a request comes in for something that requires Excel, you should create a process running a Windows Forms application. The application may have to start with no window, or you may need to start it in the context of a *[Remote Desktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892075%28VS.85%29.aspx)* connection. In any case, the task to be performed may be passed as a command line parameter, or the program can host a WCF service to have commands sent to it.

This program can call Excel just like Excel expects to be called. It can probably even handle more than one command to Excel (one at a time). However, if it hangs, the process can be killed and another one started.

I've never tried this, but it sounds like it would work better than trying to get Office Automation to do something it was not designed to do.

Comment: I KNOW we have shot ourselves in the foot, I am just asking how best to recover :) What I meant was that I just can't use an answer like "just don't use Office automation" - i.e. I was asking for CONSTRUCTIVE answers.

Comment: You've heard the old Henny Youngman joke: A man goes to the doctor, he says, "Doctor, it hurts when I do this", the doctor says, "Then don't _do_ that!". You say you're shooting yourself in the foot, you ask how to avoid powder burns and bullet holes, but you won't put down the gun.